# Interesting GCC Linking

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, linker, dynamic-linking

I was playing around with symbols and function pointers recently and noticed that though the following code runs fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    printf("%p\n",printf); // <--this line makes it work
    int (*printfptr)(const char * restrict, ...);
    printfptr = 0x1001fe910;
    (*printfptr)("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This does not:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // printf("%p\n",printf); // <-- commenting this out breaks it
    int (*printfptr)(const char * restrict, ...);
    printfptr = 0x1001fe910;
    (*printfptr)("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

(EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

How come dereferencing the exact same pointer causes issues when there is no reference to `printf` in the code? Even this works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int (*printfptr)(const char * restrict, ...);
    printfptr = 0x1001fe910;
    (*printfptr)("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
void *_ = printf; // <-- because of this
```

Why is this?

Comment: In the second case the linker doesn't know it should link against the "printf" function, so it's implementation is just not there. While in the first case the code is using `printf`, so it is linked.

Comment: If you invoke undefined behaviour, you get undefined results.  The pointer literal values are simply not guaranteed to work.  And the main problem is that without the symbolic name `printf` appearing in the code, there is no way for the system to know that it needs to make `printf` available to your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On shared objects (.so) the symbols are really resolved only at the moment of first use. By default the linker sets the option `-z lazy` which tells:

```
       When generating an executable or shared  library,  mark  it  to
       tell  the  dynamic  linker to defer function call resolution to
       the point when the function is called  (lazy  binding),  rather
       than at load time.  Lazy binding is the default.
```

You can change that behaviour by providing option `-z now`.

`man ld` for all gory details.

EDIT: Resolving a symbol is done with dynamic link API on POSIX systems. Functions `dlsym()`, `dlopen()`, `dlclose()` and `dlerror()` defined in `<dlfcn.h>`. This edition added so that you can search for these names.

Comment: On the one hand I want to upvote because it answers the OP's why question and explains how to tune the linker.  On the other hand I want to downvote because it encourages that sort of bad coding.

Comment: The thing is, sometime you need to delve on this kind of stuff. I had now two projects on which I had to resort to this API (a legacy embedded system emulation and a kind of simplified inhouse webserver that allowed for plugins that could be dynamically loaded without stopping). I generally avoid system specific stuff, but if you have to implement some specific features, there's no way around it. 
So I prefer to give at least the direction to look for even if it is not standard conform and portable.

Comment: To limit answers only to hyper-portable stuff is OK in `comp.lang.c`, on SO, I think we should also provide info about real implementations.